Color Tableau map based on two fields
I am trying to define the colors of states on a map based on two fields. The first is the total sales for each state, where I want states to be shaded light to dark. The second is whether the state has more domestic sales or foreign sales (domestic + foreign = total sales). If the state had more domestic sales it should be pink. If it had more foreign sales it should be teal. For example, Texas had high total sales but more foreign than domestic so it should be dark teal. Oregon had low total sales but had more domestic than foreign so it should be light pink.
The problem is that I can't drag both fields onto Color. If I drag one on, then the other, the second one replaces the first. If I ctrl+click both fields and try to drag them on together, only one is applied.
My domestic vs foreign color field is a calculated field based on two other calculated fields. First, Total Domestic Sales is defined as follows:

It is similar for the Total Foreign Sales field. Here is the Domestic vs Foreign Sales Rank field that determines color:

Everywhere I've searched, I've seen examples where you can put two fields onto Color, so I'm not sure why I can't do that in this case.

Your [Domestic vs Foreign Sales Rank] determines two strings, not colors. When you drag that to color and click edit colors in your marks pane, there you can assign pink and teal colors. Additionally, if you want a gradient of colors you'll need to use a continuous value not a string.

Thanks @MUFF. You're right; I did have to manually assign the colors when using the [Domestic vs Foreign Sales Rank] field as defined. For anyone wondering, in order to combine the discrete behavior of pink/teal color assignment and the continuous color shading I wanted, I had to make two map charts and use a dual axis. Here's the step-by-step for my situation:

Drag [State] onto Detail to generate the map
Ctrl+click and drag the [Latitude (generated)] pill that's on the Rows shelf to duplicate it and put another one next to the first one (so there's two of them on the Rows shelf). This generates two maps in the chart area
In the Marks card, select the first Latitude to edit the first map. Drag [SUM(Selling Price)] onto Color to make it a filled map with continuous color from dark to light
Select the second Latitude section in the Marks card to edit the other map. Drag [Domestic vs Foreign Sales Rank] onto Color to make it a filled map with two different colors. Color > Edit Colors to assign the colors
Right-click the second [Latitude (generated)] pill on the Rows shelf and select Dual Axis

